# Autoencoders' gradient when using tied weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, ties

In autoencoders when using tied weights, it was mentioned the gradient with respect to w is the sum of two weights. I didn't understand this, can someone elucidate this.

it is mentioned [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19557502/6_02_loss_function.pdf) on slide 4 in the end.

Answer (score 5):

Following the notation in the slides, a one layer autoencoder with tied weights is given by
$$o(\hat{a}(x))=o(c+W^Th(x))=o(c+W^T\sigma(b+Wx))$$

The gradient wrt $W$ according to the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial W_{ij}}=\frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat{a}_j}\frac{\partial \hat{a}_j}{\partial W_{ij}}=\frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat{a}_j}(h_i+W_{ij}\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial W_{ij}})=\frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat{a}_j}h_i+\frac{\partial l}{\partial \hat{a}_i}x_j$$
which is equal to adding up the backpropagation gradients of each layer.